# How to Restrict some part of partitioned data, So that user cant run query on that particular data set in Hive?

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-partitioning

Restrict some part of partitioned data, So that user cant run query on that particular partition in Hive

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a look here about how to ask a good question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/RANGER/Row-level+filtering+and+column-masking+using+Apache+Ranger+policies+in+Apache+Hive